# Multiple \n instances are ignored in Showdown

Tags: javascript, markdown

Can anyone help me with the issue below?

Basically, I have a JSON where the text has `\n` for a line break. I then need to parse this as markdown and convert it to HTML. The only problem is, all parsers that I've tried ignore multiple `\n` instances. To rectify this I came up with the idea below, but as you can see it really isn't very adaptable at all,  and is very clunky.

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
description = data.description.replace(/\n\n/g, "\n<br/>\n<br/>");
description = data.description.replace(/\n\n\n/g, "\n<br/>\n<br/>\n<br/>");
description = data.description.replace(/\n\n\n\n/g, "\n<br/>\n<br/>\n<br/>\n<br/>");
var html = converter.makeHtml(description);
```

Is there a way to make it so that if there is more than one `\n` in a row, it appends a `<br/>` to each `\n`?

Thanks :D

EDIT: JSON is below:

```
{
    "description": "**A glitchy apple respring animation for Anemone.**\n\n\nOriginally requested by u/Cyko__, u/Momoske (Osctardo) decided to make a \"Smoke Ball\" animation for all devices with the 7 different resolutions:\n\n- 1136x640 (iPhone 5s)\n- 1334x750 (iPhone 6/7/8)\n- 1472x828 (iPhone 6/7/8 upscaled)\n- 1920x1080 (iPhone 6+/7+/8+)\n- 2208x1242 (iPhone 6+/7+/8+ upscaled)\n- 2436x1125 (iPhone X)\n- 2688x1242 (iPhone X upscaled)\n\n\nIn the comments of the [UPCOMING] post on r/jailbreak, 2 other people (u/MatRanc and u/R3IZ4) requested for:\n\n- An *\"Apple Glitch\"* respring animation\n- A *\"Verbose\"* respring animation, which was both reworked and updated to look great on all these devices and resolutions\n\n\nThis is the *\"Apple Glitch\"* respring animation, with a black version included for those of you with an OLED device (made by myself)!"
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's a jsfiddle so you can see what happens. Just remove the `.replace()` from it and you can see what the HTML should be without the `<br/>`s: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobcxdev/t7hj5mx0/.

Comment: the third `.replace(/\n\n\n\n/g` is not needed after `.replace(/\n\n/g`

Comment: True, that actually makes it a slightly more elegant solution.

Comment: just realized that your original code probably doesn't do what you think it does, because you reassign `description` to `data.description.replace(` instead of `description.replace(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution!

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
  description = data.description.replace(/\n{2,}/g, m => m.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
description = description.replace(/<br\/>([^<])/g, "<br\/>\n\n$1");
var html = converter.makeHtml(description);
```

Credit to [Slai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383168/slai) for the first replacement!

Answer (score 1):

Surely you only need to replace each \n with a \n
:

```
description = data.description.replace(/\n/g, "\n<br/>");
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. This is because it then prevents Showdown from parsing lists correctly.